# how to Send HTML form data as PDF file from database via email function?

Tags: php, html, forms, email, pdf

I am new in php and i am working on my own project in which i have a html form.

When a user fills the form and clicks on submit all the data in form will store in database and also all data send to admin/owner in **PDF formate** via email.

**I successfully store the data in database but, I don't know how could i send a pdf file via email.**.

I have tried the following code.

```
$to = 'example@email.com';
$subject = "Website Form Data Email";
$txt = $name .' '. $addr .' '. $snpno.'  ;
$headers = "" . "\r\n" .
mail($to, $subject, $txt, $headers);
```

Please help me.

Thanks All...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*First you have to generate pdf file. *You can search in google and find some pdf generation plugin for php. Use one of them and create pdf file *And then use php mail to send mail with attachment. Here some code for [Send attachments with PHP Mail()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301358/send-attachments-with-php-mail)